# How to prevent people from creating manipulative AI nanobots?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, artificial-intelligence, nanotechnology

Set in the future where there is at least one 3D printer in every household, population demographics show aging in every part of the world. In this future, many elites have powerful AI nanobots running inside their brains to assist them with decision making as well as being informed about the relevant current event happening in the world right now. These tiny nanobots cannot replicate by themselves and have to be 3D printed. Usually people of higher social status are often manipulative and will try underhanded method such as involuntarily feeding their workers or slaves with nanobots to eavesdrop and monitor their daily activities so as to blackmail them in due time. There has been a rumor going around for sometime regarding the rich and powerful using AI nanobot to control the corporation, and even the entire nation. So what is stopping people from creating their own similar AI nanobots assuming 3D printer and materials cost are dirt cheap?

inspired by Roko's basilisk ;D

Comment: Thanks, due to your last line I now know where the name of the character "Roko Basilisk" in the webcomic https://questionablecontent.net/ stems from. :D

Comment: 3d printing at the molecular level? I don't think so anytime soon. And what does "population demographics show aging in every part of the world" have anything to do with this question?

Comment: This has nothing to do with acausal trade which is the mechanism of Roko Basilisk.

Comment: @Christian: you are right, I can't use roko's because I can't think of a way to motivate AI to torture human ;D

Comment: Not nanobots, but related enough to be [of interest](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152968/how-to-prevent-criminal-gangs-from-making-buying-guns).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**They lack the design. They lack the code. They lack the hardware.**

3D printing a nanobot is more than just hitting print. You firstly need the right hardware. 3d printers can be bought from supermarkets these days but there is a world of difference between a home printer and a commercial printer which costs many thousands of dollars more.

If you were to 3d print a gun on your home printer, chances are you'll blow your fingers/face off. A commercial printer can print a better quality gun that can be fired safely.

Next you need the design. The rich have design teams of engineers and can spend thousands of man hours and untold resources to build and test.

Finally you need the code. A nanobot needs programming as well as a body. The rich can afford to buy the best programmers and software. The poor can, at best, download some bootleg code at which they don't really know what it does or if it's loaded with malware.
The closest the poor can do to compete is with stolen hardware, designs and code which they tweak and hope for the best.

Comment: Designs and programming aren't necessarily an issue; there's always Open Source and Open Hardware. OTOH, there is indeed a huge difference between 3D printers that can do macro-scale stuff and 3D printers that can print modern electronics.

Comment: @Matthew it would certainly require quite the brave person to put an open source/hardware AI nanobot in their brain. If that were the way things were going, you can expect the FBI/CIA to have their finger in that pie, not to mention all the other problems that the open source community has...

Comment: @Matthew Majority of top notch hardware designs for most modern electronics aren't open source. And won't be until they are irrelevant. We are talking NVIDIA chipset blueprints here, not NVIDIA drivers (which indeed have been open sourced for better interoperability).

Comment: @Gnudiff The open source NVIDIA drivers developed by the community are noticeably inferior in performance from the closed source ones developed by NVIDIA.

Comment: @Michael true, but we are not even talking drivers except as for contrast. nanobot design is akin to chipset blueprints not to chipset drivers.

Comment: What is blocking you from building a drone? Nothing. What is blocking you from building a military drone? Lack of hardware (3D printer for chassis, CNC for circuit design, automated placement machine for adding chips and resistors etc. and the parts themselves), lack of software (secure communication channels, extensive testing etc.), legal concerns. Given that one nanobot is likely to get lost in action you will need loads of them. Even then, the rich likely have scanners that check outgoing signals from nanobots inside their bodies and may do random checks on employees for similar devices.

Comment: @Michael Isn't that mostly because NVIDIA tries to hide information from the open source team?

Comment: I'm not buying it - history is littered with underdogs winning over the "big guys".  Anything from the American Revolution (Brits "pffft, they are no threat"), to Dell Computer + others (did IBM even notice the start of their downfall??).  I'm thinking more like some wonderkind creating nanobots to seek and destroy nanobots.....hmmmm.

Comment: @gszavae quite the contrary, it would be very brave, or even foolish, to put a closed-source nanobot in your brain. How would you know what it really does once it's up there? How do you stay safe it once they stop providing patches?

Comment: The lot of you are missing the point. People aren't putting them in their heads. The rich and hiding them in their food/water. They don't have a choice. The rich are running custom code that they own and control. They don't need open source.

Comment: @njzk2 Unfortauntely those are both things true of open source. Who exactly is vetting entire open source software and writing their own patches? Even for extremely well used projects that is a huge problem. Implying that only closed source projects suffer this problem is not true.

Comment: @gszavae for your first point: many, many more people than are vetting closed source projects, by definition.

Comment: @njzk2 That's not correct. Many more people *could* be vetting them, but afaik there have been no studies that actually prove it. Horrendous bugs have existed within open source projects, and that's not even talking about deliberate vulnerabilities. Many open source programs rely on "oh but anyone could read the source" and don't have robust testing and validation schemes. Very very few users will ever read any of the source, almost no one (if anyone) will actually vet the source. It's a theoretical advantage, that's all.

Comment: @gszavae case in point: I opened a bug report a couple of days ago on a library that I use, and after having been able to analyse precisely what was happening, I can suggest a resolution, and possibly provide the correction. On the other hand, I am unable to do half as much on bugs found on close-source libraries.

Comment: @njzk2 Fixing a bug is a far cry from auditing a program. Try to understand what you are implying; "I fixed a bug once, therefore open source is safe from bugs and malice"? In what world does that make sense? We have had so many cases of open source projects having not only mammoth bugs but intentional back-doors. I know you are arguing ideals, not pragmatics, but at some point we need to bring it back to reality.

Comment: Chances are the software at that stage will be written by AI. People simply won't be able to read it anyway.

Comment: @gszavae it's just an example, and in no way a demonstration, but it illustrates that open source gives the possibility for users to dive into the inner workings on a piece of code, and to collaborate in making it better. Nothing of the sort can be said for closed source.

Comment: @njzk2 closed source does not rely on ad-hoc testing and debugging

Comment: @gszavae I never said it does. Unless you're implying that open source would (which, where would you get that idea from?), I'm not sure what to do of your comment.

Comment: @njzk2 the scenario you described is not normal for closed source because there are other more robust solutions in place.

Comment: @gszavae the scenario where a bug is discovered in a closed-source program is not normal? where does it say in closed-source that there are any particular solutions, robust or otherwise, in place?

Answer (score 7):

### Forbidden by 3D printers

Take some money, and try to scan it or print it. Your machine will not let you do this. There are specific protection to prevent that, the most famous one being [EURion constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation). Your 3D printer will have similar protection, detecting that you try to print a nanobot.

### Lot of data to send and process

Think of self-driving cars. They collect tons of data, and need to process them, fast. They generate Terabytes of data. Brain is even more complex than a car, so it will be several magnitude higher. Your nanobots isn't fast enough to process that much data, they send it to a central computer, that process this data. But that can be detected, and therefor regulated

Comment: This is my favorite answer - it uses existing technology to thwart counterfeiting to extrapolate an intentional limitation in consumer 3D printers that can't be circumvented without destroying the machines (or requiring a level of expertise uncommon amongst the general population).

Comment: @JBH : but that protection is only like a bicycle lock: it prevents casual crime. A very determined criminal can find a way around. One could write their own firmware to run the printer or scanner, for example.

Comment: @vsz A very determined criminal (not to point fingers, but let's say, :-) the *super wealthy*) can find their way around any and all defensive systems. There is no such thing as perfect protection. We could use some clarification from the OP, but I suspect casual crime is what he/she's talking about.  (Is the scanning prohibition firmware nowadays? It used to be mandated as burned onto the chip so it couldn't be trivially changed.)

Comment: @JBH : indeed it cannot be trivially read out and changed, but one can always write a new software from scratch. If volunteers can write entire operating system in their free time, a printer controller software is not really that far-fetched.

Comment: @vsz but that's why it was originally burned to the chip. It couldn't be rewritten by an enterprising young engineer. It had to be completely replaced by manufacture and the manufacturing chain had rules imposed on them (if I recall, criminal rules, it was the 90s when last I looked) that fundamentally stopped this in all but the most determined cases. I'd frankly be shocked if the capacity to not counterfeit money was simply a matter of firm/software. You'd have college students on every campus churning out $20 bills.

Comment: @vsz However, this does bring up another point, if I remember correctly, printer manufacturers were also required to entirely avoid the color gamut used by the pre-colorful bills. In other words, there's multiple ways the OP could impose this requirement. Make the nanites dependent on a particular alloy of titanium and then completely control the sale of that titanium, for example. Between the two restrictions it would take a very determined criminal to make the little honkers.

Comment: @JBH : burned doesn't mean it cannot be overwritten. In most chips, there are lock bits which prevent reading, but not writing. And even if the chip is somehow physically only writable once (which would then prevent firmware updates), one could buy a new micro-controller. And if that proves to be impossible, just desolder the microcontroller, and hook up another one. (like a high-end cortex, that's more then enough to implement a software in, to move the motors of the printer).

Comment: You can search online, there are people who changed the firmware in their printer and scanner so that the motor frequency is varied in a way that it plays a song. There are implementations of the video game Doom for printers.

Comment: @vsz I apologize, you seem to misunderstand. In the 90s, the chips were literally designed and burned to prohibit any such changes. (Remember you're talking to an electrical engineer.) I'm not talking about FPGAs, gate arrays, or any other type of firmware or memory. I'm talking about the control chips not having the capacity to recognize the colors (in scanning or in printing) such that they cannot (period) be replicated. There's no point to any other solution. High school students could overcome the limitation.

Comment: @JBH : my point was that you don't have to reprogram it, or replicate it. You can just remove it. And drive the mechanics with your own controller. It's much simpler to build your own controller than to manufacture the mechanical parts of the printer.

Comment: @vsz *It's much simpler to build your own controller than to manufacture the mechanical parts of the printer* I'm afraid I need to leave this conversation. You don't know enough about chip design, manufacturing, and the modification of printed circuit boards to discuss this. The mechanical components of a 3D printer are maybe 20% of the cost and effort of manufacture. Gears are easy.

Comment: @JBH : please stop making assumptions about what I know and what I don't know. You seem to deliberately misunderstand what I'm saying. I didn't mean designing and manufacturing a custom chip! I meant buying an *existing* microcontroller, and developing my own firmware for it to drive all the mechanical parts. And I wasn't even talking about 3d printers. Building an inkjet printer or suitable quality from scratch at home isn't easier than just writing software. But yeah, hooking up a different microcontroller might be an extreme solution. There are easier ways: https://youtu.be/R6k72DI0Qo0?t=32

Answer (score 6):

Printer head size. A printer with a small enough head to properly handle nanoscale poduction isnt available to the public. Why would the corporations ever sell printers with such a small size? The public will rarely need that level of detail in their printer.

Printer head shape and functioning. The shape of the printer head (and the feeding tubes) as well as how it functions can limit what materials it can handle. These printers likely have dozens if not hundreds of different printerheads, and the one's with the right shape and functions to print (malicious) nanobots just happens to be missing or always a "production error".

Materials unavailable. Nanobots are more often specific molecules that are approaching biological functions. If the right materials arent sold to the public to build the advanced versions you cant build them.

Templates unavailable. 3D printers need a template to work off so they know what to build. Its kind of hard to design a working nanobot swarm capable of even a small task, let alone the magical complexity that requires dozens if not hundreds of nanobot variants in swarms to work.

Software+computer hardware limitations. Malicious nanobot construction causes deliberate errors, making it impossible to build them unless you can build your own computer software and hardware to fix the issues. How are you going to build it? Well you are likely dependend on this 3D printer that is giving you errors whenever you try to build the parts you want...

Software checks. All printers are connected to a central hub. They detect you making specific nanobots, you get a trip through the justice system.

Nanobot sabotage. The public 3D printers all come with nanobots installed that listen in on the 3D printer and its surroundings. They notice you build nanobots that arent cleared and they'll damage the 3D printer. If the bots dont alert authorities a mechanic will (although the mechanic might think he's just ordering a specific part).

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, printers that can actually print at atomic scale (as opposed to assembling existing macro-molecules) are incredibly expensive. Further, almost all printers of any type are restricted to pre-approved designs or high-level variations on those. Designs must have maker's ID watermarked, cannot contain any auto-replication except in very specific and severely vetted designs, and must contain a number of other security features intended to restrict misuse. A printer that can avoid or fake the security features is extremely illegal. The only legal "unbridled" models are those that actually create new printers, new low-level designs, weapons . . .  These are controlled by the authorities at levels of paranoia that resemble today's methods for nuclear material and printing presses for paper money and identity documents.

I highly recommend reading Neal Stephenson's *The Diamond Age* for what I think may be a seminal view on this.